# UIWebView content loading at wrong position

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I am trying to add **three** `UIWebView` to my iOS app. I have successfully read the "HTML code" into the `UIWebView` and it displays the content fine, but one of the three views are displayed at a wrong position.

Here is the code I used to load the data:

```
-(void) webViewLoading {
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"load" ofType:@"html"];
    NSString* embedHTML = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    [self.choice_1_webview loadHTMLString: embedHTML baseURL: nil];
    [self.choice_2_webview loadHTMLString: embedHTML baseURL: nil];
    [self.choice_3_webview loadHTMLString: embedHTML baseURL: nil];
}
```

Here is what I got in the simulator:

[image: ScreenCapture]

and here is what I have in `Xcode`:

[image]

The first `UIWebView` does not load correctly and the grey rectangle is the background color of the `UIWebView`. Does anyone know what could have caused this? I created the **three** `UIWebViews` exactly the same (copied and pasted in the interface builder).

===

It looks like the content of the first `UIWebView` has a smaller height than the other two. It is weird however because the contents are generated from the same file.

Comment: Can you please show here how the webpages look when the viewed stand alone?

Comment: @Chandu It's simply "Loading..." with a rectangle around it at the top-left corner of the page. Just as what is shown on the screen.

Comment: webview.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit.   Please try this and run.

Comment: @Chandu it did not work. The first UIWebView looks like being dragged down to where there is nothing to show so that the background of the webView is shown.

Comment: @Chandu I found out that the problem is the first UIWebView.scrollView.contentOffset is somehow initialized to (0,-64). I am now manually setting it to CGPointZero, but there is still an ugly flipping when the view is loaded.